# NodeJS File Downloader with WGET?

Tags: http, node.js, download, exec, wget

I'm trying to make File Downloads with WGET method of nodejs. I found this:

```
var exec = require('exec');

// Function to download file using wget
var download_file_wget = function(file_url) {

    // extract the file name
    var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
    // compose the wget command
    var wget = 'wget -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;
    // excute wget using child_process' exec function

    var child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
    });
};
```

But it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'exec'
```

Is `exec` an another module to be installed and imported .. or how can i make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) is one of the built-in node modules

Just do

```
var url = require('url');
```

somewhere in your file.

`exec` is part of [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) so to get it do

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

Comment: Oh.. `url` is not solved but again for `exec` but i can't include `var exec = require('exec');` Is it to be installed?

Comment: You probably want to do `var exec = require('child_process').exec` - This stuff can be found pretty easily in the API docs - http://nodejs.org/api/

Comment: oh yaaa! thats it jimr. So now i changed the question to about `exec` then move your answer as new one. Coz i want to make it as an accepted Answer. Thanks ;)